# Run "Assign Macro" dialog box programmatically

Tags: vba, excel

Im creating macro tool that allows programmatically create buttons in excel, but at the end i need to invoke "Assign macro" dialog box:

[image]

to let user choose what macro he wants assign to created button. How i can achieve that?

Actual code:

```
Dim btn As Shape
Set btn = wsSheetToAddButton.Shapes.AddFormControl(Type:=xlButtonControl, Left:=buttonLocation.Left, Top:=buttonLocation.Top, Width:=128, Height:=75)
With btn
    With .TextFrame.Characters
        .Caption = buttonText
        With .Font
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
            .ColorIndex = textColor
        End With
    End With
.Select
End With
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this after selecting the button:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogAssignToObject).Show
```

Comment: Great! Working like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign the "macro" from the code, this is some minimal example:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim btn As Shape
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(Type:=xlButtonControl, _
                                Left:=5, Top:=5, Width:=75, Height:=75)
    btn.OnAction = "Testing"

End Sub
```

or refering the newly created button, [as mentioned by @Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682079/5448626):

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim btn As Shape        
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(Type:=xlButtonControl, _
                                Left:=5, Top:=5, Width:=75, Height:=75)
    btn.Select: Application.Dialogs(xlDialogAssignToObject).Show

End Sub
```

Comment: I noticed that without btn.Select before btn.Application.Dialogs, I'm getting reference exception

Comment: @user1916778 - that's true unfortunatelty. Obviously I was having something selected already, when I have tested it. But there should be some way without using `.Select` I guess.